# How do i use set_focus_child to set focus to a text entry in gtkmm?

Tags: gtkmm

I have a dialog in which i ask the user to enter username and password. I match them with database. If the user field is empty, i show a message box telling the user that user id is blank. I want the focus to set to user id field. How do i do that in gtkmm? Is it possible to clear the existing contents of the user id?

```
l_user_id=m_user_id->get_text();
l_password=m_password->get_text();

if(l_user_id=="")
  throw_dialog("Empty Field","Please enter a user name");
  // i want to clear the user id field
  // i want to set focus to user id field
```

Comment: I can clear the contents of the user id field by using set_text().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Gtk::Widget::grab_focus()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a4c376dd31e5b4d616d8f914338fea8b6) and [Gtk::Entry::set_text](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Entry.html#aaee5b96d2ffea0342aa4c93fbfe24433).

```
l_user_id.set_text("");
l_user_id.grab_focus();
```

Comment: m_user_id->grab_focus(); Thanks a lot Mark.